# How to disable cells in Tapkulibrary?

Tags: iphone, xcode, tapku

I'm wondering if there's a way to disable days in calendar, to be not chosen. I use tapkulibrary to show calendar and I also added some marks. Now I'm trying to disable those cells which are not marked, so they could not be chosen.

Is that possible?